# Как регулярными выражениями получить определённый набор символов?

Tags: c#, строки, url

есть строка

```
string s = "http://captcha.site.com/captcha?key=5d11165823bed8a529794a6253f7ec6fab099f8f748424efddb2506f4dfe";
```

как получить всё что идёт после "key=" ?, т.е. "5d11165823bed8a529794a6253f7ec6fab099f8f748424efddb2506f4dfe"

Comment: Не нужна здесь регулярка. Достаточно метода string.Split('=').

Answer (score 11):

А давайте попробуем сделать правильно и надёжно! Все средства есть.

```
using System.Web;

// ...

var s = "http://captcha.site.com/captcha?key=5d11165823bed8a52979" + 
        "4a6253f7ec6fab099f8f748424efddb2506f4dfe";
var uri = new Uri(s);
var query = uri.Query;
var parts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
var key = parts["key"];
```

Вам придётся подключить сборку System.Web.

Зачем регулярки, если есть готовый парсер?

Comment: ну потому что мне нужна регулярка)

Comment: @inkorpus: Регулярки — не самый лучший инструмент для парсинга.

Comment: мне строка в виде другого метода возвращается, и теперь из строки надо выцепить ключ)

Comment: @inkorpus: Ну да, и код из ответа именно это и делает. Это и есть парсинг URI. Не забывайте, что части после `=` могут быть закодированы (`https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%89%D1%8C`), мой код это автоматически раскодирует.

Comment: мне не нужно делать как вы предлагаете, мне нужно то что я просил)

Comment: @inkorpus вам шашечки или ехать? То есть рабочее оптимальное решение или домашнее задание сдать?

Comment: К слову: у Microsoft есть NuGet-пакет `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`, являющийся PCL - в нем указанный метод реализован как метод расширения класса Uri. Возможно кому-то будет полезно при разработке под платформы отличные от Windows, дабы не городить велосипед. )

Answer (score 3):

```
[?&]key=(\w+)
```

Взять первую группу.

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить регулярным выражениям: `https?:\/\/[^\s]+?key=([A-z0-9]*)`

Comment: ошибка "Нераспознанная управляющая последовательность"

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string InputStr = "http://captcha.site.com/captcha?key=5d11165823bed8a529794a6253f7ec6fab099f8f748424efddb2506f4dfe";
        var match = Regex.Match(InputStr, "[\?&]key=(?<key>\\w+)");
        var key = match.Groups["key"].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Внес маленькую правку для улучшения качества ответа.

Comment: @ReinRaus, лучше проверку на вопрос или амперсанд, а не на границу слова. Кстати, добавил такую в свой ответ, а то что-то я сразу про это не подумал.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, так лучше. Только лучше это написать так: `[\?&]`

Comment: @ReinRaus, согласен. Кстати, при квадратных скобках экранирование вопроса не требуется.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, это не нужно, просто я привык экранировать мета-символы там, где они выступают как литералы. Так потом проще воспринимать регулярное выражение.