# Можно ли как-то получить json для пост запроса

Tags: c#, httpclient, json.net

[Вот этот json нужно получить, ниже что в ответе приходит.
Я не могу тупо копировать. мне нужно это программно делать, ибо ссылка может менятся, следовательно параметры тут тоже](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j59S.png)

У меня в фиддлере выдает json при отправке post запроса(Это не ответ уже приходит, а сам зпрос)

```
{"clientId":"b2c:ru","lang":"ru","currencyId":1,"departureCountryId":210357,"departureCityId":274286,"arrivalCountryId":20613,"arrivalRegionIds":[],"arrivalCityIds":[],"adults":2,"children":[],"minStartDate":"2020-06-05","maxStartDate":"2020-06-05","minNightsCount":7,"maxNightsCount":14,"hotelIds":[]}
```

Как я могу получать этот json программно?

Я предполагаю это делается с помощью get запроса, но как-то не получается

Вот код:

```
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Cbot");
     var html = await client.GetAsync("https://....");
      Console.WriteLine(html.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
         var jsonresponse =await html.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

Comment: Если вам фиддлер показал запрос с ответом в виде JSON, тогда я не пойму, в чем проблема? Копируйте тип запроса, заголовки, куки и получайте то, что надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сейчас скриншот приложу, я не могу словами объяснить нормально

Comment: Ну для начала, это "Запрос", а запросы составляют сайты, вы не можете их взять просто так, ибо если вы эмулируете это запрос, то и его составление лежит на вас. Другими словами, все данные, что в этом JSON вы должны найти на сайте, найти от куда они берутся, составить этот JSON и отправить. Во вторых, если в запросе JSON, то это явно не GET, а POST. В третьих вы пишете человеку ниже "получаю html, а не json" - все потому, что вы не отправляете нужные заголовки, например по вашей картинке виден `x-requested-with`, который обычно говорит сайту "Ей, мне нужны данные в формате xml/json".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ скорее всего данные берутся из ссылки. Значит я должен обрезать ссылку и брать значения. Нету библиотек которые облегчат это дело, что они могли по словам искать и обрезать, обычным сабстрингом геморно немного будет

Comment: Это только вам известно должно быть от куда все эти значения, я могу лишь посоветовать вам нажать в фидлере Ctrl+F (в левом окне) и по всем запросам начать поиск нужного вам значения из JSON, не забудьте там поставить галку на декодирование ответа! По поводу ссылки, конечно [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432690/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 1):

Newtonsoft.Json большая C# либа для работой с JSON.

```
public class JSONData
{
    public string clientId;
    public string lang;
    public int currencyId;
    public decimal departureCountryId;
    .........
}
using System.Net;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
request.Method = "POST/GET";
request.ContentType = "......";
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Cbot");
try
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {   
                streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(то что 
                отправить));
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new 
                   StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                JSONData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONData> 
                                (response);
            }   
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {.....}
```

Comment: Я знаю про эту библиотеку и использую её, у меня немного другая проблема. Проблема в том, что как я делаю, get запрос возвращает мне html, а мне нужно как-то json выудить

Comment: тоесть jsonresponse из вашего кода = {"clientId":"b2c:ru","lang":"ru","currencyId":1,"departureCountryId":210357,"departureCityId":274286,"arrivalCountryId":20613,"arrivalRegionIds":[],"arrivalCityIds":[],"adults":2,"children":[],"minStartDate":"2020-06-05","maxStartDate":"2020-06-05","minNightsCount":7,"maxNightsCount":14,"hotelIds":[]} и Вы хотите его "распарсить"?

Comment: Нет, это у меня идет для отправки пост запроса. А после пост запроса, мне идет ответ уже нужный мне json. Но смотрите, мне приходит в `jsonresponse` html, а не json

Comment: Смотрите, либо я тут код не допонял, либо вы меня. Суть в том, что у меня будет кучу ссылок с разными параметрами, эти параметры будут так же менятся в json, мне нужно чтобы автоматически я мог получить json, который мне нужно буде отправить с пост запросом. Есть ли такой метод, или нет?